# is it possible to load different html (index) page according to the screen size?

Tags: html, css

i have designed 3 different designs for my website. one for mobile , one for tablets and one for desktop. is it possible to load these html(index) pages according to the screen size. i.e i want mobile.html to load when viewing the website on a mobile. similarly for tab and desktop. i know about the media queries for css . but wanted to know is there a way to load different html pages according to the screen size. THANK YOU in advance.

Comment: It might help if you told us why you want to use this approach (when [RWD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) is pretty much the current best practice)—we may be able to suggest ways of achieving what you want without loading different HTML pages. The [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com)—a site where a single, unchanging page of HTML is styled with a variety of different style sheets—has recently been revitalised and should give you an idea of what you can achieve by CSS-only changes.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use Php or javascript to load an HTML file/content accordingly
2) use media queries, which are quite useful in this case. All you need t have is different CSS/styles based on different screen sizes. They won,t load a new HTML....